# Как задать фон блоков?

Tags: html, css

Как разделить страницу на блоки (css) и задать фон каждого из блоков? Нужно разделить страницу на блоки и задать фон каждого из них. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Как разделить страницу на блоки, это вы уже сами смотрите. Чтобы определить бэкграунд для каждого отдельного блока, воспользуйтесь одним из CSS-правил:

```
background-color:#fff;
background-image:url("pic.jpg");
background: url("pic.jpg") #fff;  /* если вдруг картинка будет недоступной */
```

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, как создавать и работать с "блоками" (чаще это называют слои, если я правильно понял, о чём вы) - это целая отдельная тема.
Если вкратце - чтобы сделать слой, создайте блочный элемент -

> `<div></div>`

У него вы можете задать любые свойства, необходимые вам (ширину/высоту, цвет, положение на экране и т.п.). Делается это через свойства CSS
Например

> `<div style="backgroung-color: red; width: 100px; height: 100px; position: absolute; >top: 50px; left: 20px;">Содержимое слоя</div>`

А задать фон можно, как уже написали выше, одним из свойтв:

> `background-color: yellow;`
>
> `background-image: url(ссылка на изображение)`
>
> `ещё можно на всякий случай написать свойство background: no-repeat; чтобы фон не повторялся`

Более подробно о любых свойствах CSS и HTML можно узнать [тут](http://htmlbook.ru)

Answer (score -1):

.XXX{
background:url('https://www.interfax.ru/ftproot/photos/photostory/2019/11/08/foto316.jpg');}

.xxx имя класса